# What is the correct way to say One and Two-sided Limits?

Tags: word-choice

I'm talking about limits in calculus. The text itself is for the header of the one and two sided limits section. There are a different ways I can think of doing this but I'm not sure which one is right.

- One and Two-sided Limits
- One-sided and Two-sided Limits
- One and Two Sided Limits

What is the correct way to write this?

Comment: Lower and upper bounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the three is correct. The correct way to write the phrase is

> One- and Two-Sided Limits

*One-*, followed by *Two-Sided* is the shorthand way of saying

> One-Sided and Two-Sided Limits,

which would also be a correct way to word the phrase.

Comment: I like your second option better. Is wikipedia doing the same heading wrong? "One-sided limits" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit

Comment: Wikipedia's heading is fine as it is, but that's because it's missing what your phrase has; namely, "two-sided. "